# Add column to PFUser AFTER signup? Parse, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfuser

I would like my user to add/edit details about their profile after they register with my app.

```
@IBAction func doneEditting(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.completeEdit()
}

func completeEdit() {
    var user = PFUser()
    user["location"] = locationTextField.text

    user.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if let error = error {
            let errorString = error.userInfo?["error"] as? NSString
            println("failed")
        } else {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Editted", sender: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

the breakpoint stops right at user.saveInBackgroundWithBlock. No of the docs show how to append new columns after the signup.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are mentioning that the user should be able to edit their profile after they have registered. When registering a user with Parse using `signUpInBackgroundWithBlock`, then the Parse SDK will automatically create a `PFUser` for you.

In your provided code you are creating and saving a completely new `PFUser` instead of getting the one which is currently logged in. If you are not using the `PFUser` which is logged in, then you will get the following error at `user.saveInBackgroundWithBlock` (which you are also mentioning in your post):

```
User cannot be saved unless they are already signed up. Call signUp first
```

---

To fix this, you will need to change:

```
var user = PFUser()
```

To the following:

```
var user = PFUser.currentUser()!
```

The rest of your code (for example `user["location"] = locationTextField.text`) works fine and will dynamically/lazily add a new column to your `User` database (which is what you want).

Answer (score 0):

Parse allows you to add columns to a class lazily, meaning that you can add a field to your PFObject and if it is not present in your Parse class, Parse will add that column for you.

Here's example how you would add a column via code:

```
// Add the new field to your object
yourObject["yourColumnName"] = yourValue
yourObject.saveInBackground()
```

You'll notice that Parse will create a new column named `yourColumnName` on their web portal.

reference from [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31282599/how-to-add-another-column-to-my-class-in-parse-com-swift).

Comment: Thank you! I will try this, in the meantime I just created all of the parts of class during sign up and left blank values and then hid them until the user changed them.